# How to know what goes wrong in angular 2

Tags: debugging, angular, ide

It's the kind of question I would have never expected to make.

How do I get any pointer to what is wrong with my app in angular 2.

- I don't get any message in the terminal where I run npm start
- I can't see any logs file
- I only get the "Loading..." screen and nothing interesting in source code either.

I've tried with different IDEs (Atom, Visual Studio Code) but they just check what's wrong with typescript (nothing in this case).

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Solved by using Firefox > Tools > Web Developer > Browser Console
Click on the error at the end, a window will open on the right, and browse the error message.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check if `boostrap()` is called and add `console.log()` to the constructor of the `AppModule` and `AppComponent` class so you can check if they are instantiated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question to clarify that I guess AppComponent and App Module are working because my app is running perfectly until I import one of my components in the AppModule and it just stops working, without giving me any notification. How do I know what's wrong? I'll try what you say, I'll have to check what you mean.

Comment: Also try to just refresh your page with the web tools console open, sometimes picks up errors not shown on initial start up

Comment: Please show how you import components to `AppModule` if this causes the app to fail.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that bootstrap() is deprecated. platformBrowserDynamic is the new way of Bootstrapping your Angular app. Try to follow the Angular quick start tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I already did the quick start and it doesn't mention anything about the web console. Actually everything comes to realising Angular is, at the end of the day, pure JavaScript.